# Angular make array of object my data in json

Tags: angular

I am using angular I want to change my data to array of object

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="post(myForm.value)">
    <ul>
      <div *ngFor="let obj of data">
        <p value='obj.username'>{{obj.username}}</p>
        <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)] = obj.custom /></td>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Mark as Absent</button>
</form>
```

.ts

```
post(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

on submit i want this format

```
[
    {username:test, custom:1},
    {username:test2, custom:2}
]
```

How to make this as expected format

Answer (score 0):

You can `push` it to an empty array and maintain that in the class object as below,

```
arrayOfAbsentees=[]
post(data){
    this.arrayOfAbsentees.push(data)

}
```

Comment: @myTest can I see your complete code as many pieces are missing

Comment: can you please give a example on it

Comment: @myTest I want to see the `data` object when the component is initialized

Comment: [
    {"_id":"5ca1f85ef7ae1632341ef0d6","username":"test","__v":0},{"_id":"5ca1f877f7ae1632341ef0f4","username":"test2",,"__v":0}
]